# Emacs org-mode: how to hide the enumerated list items descriptions by default

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Suppose we have this org file:

```
1. first item
   description of the first item
2. second item
   description of the second item
3. third item
   description of the third item
```

If I move the cursor to all the top items, and click `<tab>`, it will hide the descrption. And the file will look like this:

```
1. first item...
2. second item...
3. third item...
```

But when I open the file all items are open, which is uncomfortable for me. How can I hide them by default, leaving just dots?

Answer (score 1):

That's strange, for me this is the default behavior to hide everything except the top level.
You can either modify it globally via the customize menu : `Group org startup -> option org-startup-folded`

or for each file like this http://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html#Initial-visibility

Comment: What value should I set for `org-startup-folded` variable? It didn't work for me for "overview" and "content".

Comment: What if you add `#+STARTUP: overview` in the file and reload it ?

Comment: "What if you add #+STARTUP: overview in the file and reload it ?" - this was the first thing I did - doesn't work. What version of Emacs are you using? Mine is 24.3.1 / Windows 7

Comment: I have the same config. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Maybe something in your .emacs ?